# Prisma reverses manual changes made in migration file

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I am trying to manually configure full text search for Postgresql. I have followed the instructions on how to manually modify migration files located at:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/migrate/developing-with-prisma-migrate/customizing-migrations

When I run prisma migrate with the manually modified migration file, Prisma comes back with another migration that reverses my changes.

Here is the manually modified file:

[image: Screenshot 2023-05-05 at 6 36 39 PM]

And here is the migration that Prisma creates to reverse it:

[image: Screenshot 2023-05-05 at 6 38 50 PM]

I have done this same process to create triggers and Prisma does NOT reverse those changes. How do I get Prisma to let me add these full text features.

Thanks